# Azure AD B2C Custom Policy and Graph API - MethodNotAllowed

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I try to acces some elements of Graph API in an Azure AD B2C Custom Policy.
I am able to acquire a token  but when I call the graph API, I have a Bad request error.

I tested the process with postman and it works.

Below the code.

```
<ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>TEST  GET BEARER</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="REST-AcquireAccessToken">
          <DisplayName></DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://login.microsoftonline.com/myB2Ctenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token</Item>
            <Item Key="AuthenticationType">Basic</Item>
            <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Form</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <CryptographicKeys>
            <Key Id="BasicAuthenticationUsername" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_StagingSecureRESTClientId" />
            <Key Id="BasicAuthenticationPassword" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_StagingSecureRESTClientSecret" />
          </CryptographicKeys>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="grant_type" DefaultValue="client_credentials" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="scope" DefaultValue="https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="bearerToken" PartnerClaimType="access_token" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
         
      </TechnicalProfiles>  
    </ClaimsProvider>
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>TEST  CALL Graph API</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="REST-GetProfile">
          <DisplayName>Get user extended profile Azure Function web hook</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/userId/memberOf</Item>        <!--User hard coded for testing purposes -->
            <Item Key="AuthenticationType">Bearer</Item>
            <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Body</Item>
            <Item Key="UseClaimAsBearerToken">bearerToken</Item>
            <Item Key="AllowInsecureAuthInProduction">false</Item>
          </Metadata>     
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="bearerToken"/>
          </InputClaims>           
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>  
    </ClaimsProvider>
```

The code is called via ValidationTechnocalProfile:

```
 <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="REST-AcquireAccessToken" />
<ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="REST-GetProfile" />
```

Note that when I want to access the user profile ([https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{userId}](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/%7BuserId%7D), the error is MethodNotAllowed.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

- No information in Application insights

Answer (score 0):

I had a closer look to the documentation (not only the examples).
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/restful-technical-profile

I was using the POST Method (SendClaimsIn == Body). I changed it to Url and I am able to call the Graph API